# Atributo com 2 palavras não pega CSS

Tags: html, css

Olá, porque esse atributo usando 2 palavras não pega, e o que uso somente 1 palavra pega

```
<li data-nome="testejunto">Teste</li>
```

Exemplo que pega:

```
.item[data-nome=testejunto] {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Exemplo que não pega

```
.item[data-nome=teste separado] {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize aspas para delimitar o valor do atributo no CSS assim como fez no HTML:

```css
input[type="text 2"] {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="text 2"]:focus {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The width Property</h1>

<p>Set the width of the input field to 100 pixels. However, when the input field gets focus, make it 250 pixels wide:</p>

Search: <input type="text 2" name="search">
```